# SQLiteStudio не заполняет автоматически поле, хотя я указал заполнение в python

Tags: python, sqlite3

Здравствуйте дорогие пользователи!

Дело такое, я соединен Python с помощью sqlite3 с sqlite. Сделал так, чтобы по умолчанию ставилось значение 1:

[image: Сделал так, чтобы по умолчанию ставилось значение 1.]

В итоге при сохранении никакого числа не ставится. Смотрю [старый курс](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCdyfEvrIUg&list=PLA0M1Bcd0w8x4Inr5oYttMK6J47vxgv6J&index=2), может там уже неверно показывают?

[image: Скрин того что не работает автозаполнение]
Если проблема в курсе, скиньте пожалуйста более актуальную информацию, а если в моем коде буду очень благодарен помощи.

Comment: Нужно привести **весь код,** которым вы создали таблицу, заполнили ее и сохранили, но не как картинки, а **в текстовом виде** (copy / paste).

Comment: Как вы заполнили эту таблицу — вручную (напр.  в программе DB Browser for SQLite), или кодом в Питоне?

Answer (score 0):

Вы, наверно, сделали такую постепенность шагов

- сначала вы в Питоне *сделали код* для создания таблицы, пока **без** `DEFAULT 1`,
- затем вы запустили этот код, чем вы таблицу (в вашей датабазе `dsa`) *создали*,
- затем вы  в программе DB Browser for SQLite *открыли* датабазу `dsa` и в ней действительно увидели эту таблицу (пока пустую, вез дат),
- затем вы в Питоне *добавили* `DEFAULT 1` и *запустили* измененный код,
- затем вы в программе DB Browser for SQLite *попробовали добавить дата* в таблицу, а **`DEFAULT 1` не сработало.**

Почему не сработало?

Потому что перед последним шагом **вы забыли в программе DB Browser for SQLite закрыть датабазу и затем ее снова открыть**, чтобы изменения из предпоследнего шага могли проявиться.